# Python - 'Error: AudioFileOpen failed ('wht?')', play audio file on pong game

Tags: python, audio, os.system

I'm making Pong Game with Python
and wanna put an audio file in it.

but the file doesn't play with this error message

```
Error: AudioFileOpen failed ('wht?')
```

here is my part of code. (I imported os module on top.)

```
if ball.ycor() > 290:
    ball.sety(290)
    ball.dy *= -1
    os.system('afplay bounce.wav')
```

The audio file (bounce.wav) is in same directory with Pong game python file. I don't know what the problem is.

please help me, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, that runs and reproduces your problem. Maybe include what you tried and ask a specific question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the absolute path to the afplay. Try using this:

```
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sound_path = os.path.join(dir_path, 'bounce.wav')

if ball.ycor() > 290:
    ball.sety(290)
    ball.dy *= -1
    os.system('afplay "{}"'.format(sound_path))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the playsound module instead:

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('afplay bounce.wav')
```